# DataBinding Eval To 2 Decimal Place Doesn't Show 0

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding

Platform: C# ASP.NET 3.5

I have a ListView which builds a Rate field which is decimal, if I simply have `<% #Eval("Rate") %>` it shows 4.5000 rather than 4.5 if I use `<% #Eval("Rate","{0:#.##}") %>` it shows 4.5 but doesn't display 0

any suggests on how to bind the decimal field but still show 0

Thanks

Lee

Comment: You can work these formatting strings out more easily by using Chris Sell's .NET FormatDesigner- http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/#FormatDesigner

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using `#.##` in the format means it should hide 0. Use `0.00` instead:

```
<%# Eval("Rate", "{0:0.00}") %>
```

See these examples:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);   // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);      // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);      // "123.00"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);   // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4);      // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);      // "123"
```

Answer (score 11):

Did you try this :

```
<% #Eval("Rate","{0:F2}") %>
```

Comment: This is a better/clean solution

Answer (score 1):

This would work, it also adds a group separator: `<%# Eval("Rate", "{0:n2}")%>`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `<% #Eval("Rate","{0:F2}") %>`
I also use: `style="text-align:right"`
Instead of trying to make the format do the correct number of digits.
Of course this could also be a CSS setting in the css file, instead of inline CSS.

Answer (score -3):

At server side Convert Decimal 2 place into 1 place.
(Decimal Value).ToString("0.0");