# ASP.NET determine number of digits after decimal point on GridView.RowDataBound

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am binding data to my GridView control and in one of the columns I have a price column which is of type double.
I also have a key in the web.config file that tells me how many digits to display after decimal point.

I want to display the data bound field according to that key in the web.config.

I saw this post on how to set the number of digists after decimal point: [DataBinding Eval To 2 Decimal Place Doesn't Show 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123926/databinding-eval-to-2-decimal-place-doesnt-show-0)

but I need a way of doing that with a variable that tells how many decimal places to use.

I tried this:

```
 Private Sub grdData_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdData.RowDataBound

    Dim numOfDigitsAfterDecimal = Integer.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("numOfDigitsAfterDecimal"))

    Dim d As String = ""
    For Z As Integer = 0 To numOfDigitsAfterDecimal - 1
        d = d + "#"
    Next

    e.Row.Cells(3).Text = String.Format("{0:0.{1}}", Double.Parse(e.Row.Cells(3).Text), d)

End Sub
```

but it does not work, however if I do:

```
e.Row.Cells(3).Text = String.Format("{0:0.##}", Double.Parse(e.Row.Cells(3).Text))
```

it does work and displays 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `N0` or `N1` or `N2` and so the number will show the decimal place. check this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) 
Example :

```
  number.ToString("N3")
```

> //          N:                     1,054.32
>
> //          N0:                    1,054
>
> //          N1:                    1,054.3
>
> //          N2:                    1,054.32
>
> //          N3:                    1,054.322

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this format option, it does the trick, however it causes my GridView to add an empty blank row at the top.

Comment: you are welcome. it should not do that check your datasource and be sure if everything is fine.